# How to use a external Javascript class in html?

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file which has a class defined. I want to call this class from `<script>` from another html file.

component.js:

```
class TryClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHi() {
    alert( this.name );
  }
}
```

main.html:

```
<html>
<script src="./component.js" />

<script>
var user = new TryClass( "John" );
user.sayHi();
</script>

<body>
</body>
```

This doesn't show the alert when I load main.html (from my webserver). 
However, with the inspect console, I am able to use the TryClass.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

after test i think the problem is your format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="component.js"></script>
    <script>
        var user = new TryClass("John");
        user.sayHi();
    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

you lost`</script>` after `<script src="./component.js" />`,i guess this is the worst error though you also lost `</html>` and `<head></head>`

Answer (score -1):

Please try by

```
var TryClass = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}

TryClass.prototype.sayHi = function () {
    alert( this.name );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Your answer is in ES5 format and the author's post is in ES6 for describing a class.